# Как работать с буфером экрана C#

Tags: c#, .net

Можете подсказать, как и вообще можно ли работать с буфером экрана на C#
Буду благодарен за любой пример.
Спасибо заранее

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions и ещё https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.console?view=net-6.0

Comment: Что именно подразумеваете под словом "буфер"? Буфер консоли? Графический буфер? Объясните, что именно хотите делать. Скриншоты получать?